# jQuery .toggle stacking styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem where I'm using .toggle to slide elements up and down, the problem is when i try to move my cursor quickly over the items it gets messed up. The id of the element is removed and I get custom styling assigned by jQuery.

```
<div class="ui-effects-wrapper" style="font-size: 100%; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 160px; height: 60px; float: none; position: relative; z-index: auto; top: -50px; left: auto; bottom: auto; right: auto; overflow: hidden; display: block; background: transparent;">Novi test</div>
```

How do I fix this? I've tried using .stop but it doesn't solve the problem. I've tried reducing the animation time but the problem persists.

.js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.journal-entry').hover(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).find('div').stop()
    $(this).find('div').toggle("slide", { direction: "down" }, 200).html(name);
},                        function(){ 
    $(this).find('div').stop();
    $(this).find('div').toggle("slide", { direction: "down" }, 200);
});

});
```

HTML

```
<li class="col-md-3 journal-entry" name="Name of the img">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="journal-img" src="imgsrc">
            <div id="journal-img-title">Novi test</div>
        </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the selector and adding a class

```
$('.journal-entry').hover(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    $("a",this).children('.titler').toggle("slide", { direction: "down" }, 200).html(name);
},                        function(){ 
    $("a",this).children('.titler').toggle("slide", { direction: "down" }, 200);
});
```